# Similar to the chart function in MS Excel, given set of numbers generate mathematical equation to describe set

Tags: c++, algorithm, excel, math, logarithm

I'm trying to work up a prototype archive format that can better survive data corruption. My schema is to convert every character to decimal and then plot the data.

For example:

S      o      m      e     _

83 111 109 101 32 ........ 115

Once plotted, ^ these ^ numbers can be described by the function: -18.04*ln(x) + 124.14

Since every set of numbers will be plotted using the natural log, I plan on appending a float to the end of every line in the form of [is_neg][first_num][second_num], e.g. 11804124.14

The first number will always be a Boolean representing if it is negative or positive.
The next four numbers will always be the coefficient of ln. 
The last 5 numbers will always be constant term. If it is less than one hundred, it will be prefixed with a 0.

None of that is really important. I figured that was the best way to represent the data. If anyone has a better idea, I'd love to hear it (seriously).

Currently I am doing this in Excel. I highlight the numbers, chart wizard, etc, add logarithmic plot line.

So here is my question. Is there a way, algorithmically, given a set of two or more numbers to generate a logarithmic function? It would be super sweet if there was a pre-defined class somewhere for this. I tried searching around but couldn't find anything. I figured .Net might have something for this, considering it's an excel feature.

On a side note, just in case anyone is curious, I plan on adding adding the equation to the end of the line (like I previously said). For archive corruption detection and repair I'm going to traverse every row and compute the equation that best describes that row. If the value is extremely off (say more than 20%) then I will conclude either that the archive is either too far damaged for repair or that the metadata is corrupt.

If the set value is within tolerance, my plan for repairing the archive would be to do a permutation on each value in the row and calculate the equation associated with it. The per-mutated set that most closely fits with the function would be considered the "correct" set.

Complicated, yes? I'm open to ideas as well. Thanks a lot for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is probably best computed using a [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) (using [least squares approximationo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares)) of the data, after you transforme said data using the logarithm.

On the whole I doubt your scheme will be very useful, since computing those logarithms is rather expeonsive and reconstructing data from that line will be hard. For ideas on the subject, have a look at [forward error correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction).